# ggplot error: ssh X11 forwarding

Tags: r, ssh, ggplot2, x11

I am using ggplot over ssh and running into the following error:

`ggplot(data)` outputs the following error

`X11 font -adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*, face 1 at size 9 could not be loaded`

It appears this could be due to several issues. Is there anyone work around/solution? I'm using R-3.3.0

Comment: I didn't understand if you're launching a script remotely or using a graphical session over ssh (i.e. ssh -X etc.). If it's the second case, try running only the R script on the shell (it's something like R --vanilla script-to-execute, but see man page) and see if the graphs saved by ggplot2 are now ok.

Comment: Is it really an error or just warning? Did you try to install that font?

Comment: @Jakue It's an error. It's not outputting the plot, but throwing an error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [extrafont](https://github.com/wch/extrafont) package to manage what font ggplot2 is using and potentially change this to something available on the system that is drawing the plot.

```
    require(extrafont)
    extrafont::font_import()  ## first time could take a while
    extrafont::loadfonts()
    ggplot_font <- extrafont::choose_font(c(“Helvetica", "Arial”))  ## or enter a system font that is available
```

Then add to your plot `+ theme(text = element_text(family = ggplot_font)`

You can see what fonts are available after `extrafont::loadfonts()` using `extrafont::fonttable()`